# Is there a way to get only the Reply Text from SendGrid Inbound Parse API?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I am successfully getting emails from the SendGrid Parse API.  My application sends an email with HTML content to a user and when the user replies from any email client, I am parsing the email and have the html and text attributes of the reply from SendGrid's parsing.

An example text string parameter from the SendGrid Parse payload:

```
'This is a gmail reply On Mon, Dec 20, 2021 at 10:21 PM <testaccount@parse.mytestdomain.com> wrote:> This is the original email text'
```

Where the reply text is `This is a gmail reply`
and the Original email text is `This is the original email text`

Is there anyway to parse the reply and remove the original quoted text without a Regex of every possible email client treatment of replies??

Comment: I am looking for the same.